# Salvar definições da página ao recarregá-la

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, eu fiz uma páigna na web com uma opção de modo noturno através de um switch. Gostaria de saber se é possível de armazenar o estado do switch para aquela pessoa que está na página quando ela entrar em uma subpágina etc. Atualmente, sempre que eu mudo de página ele volta ao estado inicial.

O que eu fiz até agora: https://jsfiddle.net/hvj6a0hp/

Fiz utilizando HTML, CSS e JavaScript

Comment: Você pode usar Cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `localStorage` com os valores "1" para fundo claro e "2" para fundo escuro adicionando as **linhas comentadas** abaixo no seu código:

```
mode.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if(mode.checked == true) {
    localStorage.estilo = "2"; // valor para layout escuro
    body.style.setProperty('--bg', 'var(--dark)');
    body.style.setProperty('--text', 'var(--light)');
    body.style.setProperty('--styleback', 'var(--trueback)');
  }
  else {
    localStorage.estilo = "1"; // valor para layout claro
    body.style.setProperty('--bg', 'var(--light)');
    body.style.setProperty('--text', 'var(--dark)');
    body.style.setProperty('--styleback', 'var(--falseback)');
  }
});
```

Adicione um "gatilho" quando a página for totalmente carregada:

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    if(localStorage.estilo == "2"){
        $("#mode").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Quando a página for carregada, o script acima irá verificar o valor do `localStorage` e aplicar a mudança.